# How do I display a message if a jsf datatable is empty?

Tags: java, jsf

Using JSF1.2, if my datatable binding returns no rows I want to display a message saying so.

How do I do that?

And for extra points - how do I hide the table completly if it's empty?

Thanks.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute. It accepts a boolean expression. You can evaluate the datatable's value inside the expression with help of the EL's `empty` keyword. If it returns `false`, the whole component (and its children) won't be rendered.

```xml
<h:outputText value="Table is empty!" rendered="#{empty bean.list}" />

<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

For the case you're interested, here are other basic examples how to make use of the EL powers inside the `rendered` attribute:

```xml
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue gt 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue eq null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue ne 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{not empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{not bean.booleanValue and bean.intValue ne 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.enumValue eq 'ONE' or bean.enumValue eq 'TWO'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE 7 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partwebtier.htm#BNADP) - [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el.htm#GJDDD) - [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el005.htm#BNAIK)

Comment: does the #{not empty bean.list} work with array, BalusC? If not, how do we check if an array is empty or not?

Comment: @Harry: Yes, `empty` works for arrays (and strings) as well. If it fails for you ask a question.

Comment: In PrimeFaces exists `emptyMessage`.

Comment: @Alexander: Question is about JSF 1.2.

Comment: That is for sure :) . I just want to comment it here, because sometimes, people browse those questions and it could be a hint.

Comment: I realize this is 6 years old, but this does not seem to work if the list is a javax.faces.model.DataModel?  What is the pattern to use in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can test this in several ways, for example by having a function in a bean that tests the list size:

```
function boolean isEmpty() {
    return myList.isEmpty();
}
```

then in the JSF pages :

```
<h:outputText value="List is empty" rendered="#{myBean.empty}"/>

<h:datatable ... rendered="#{!myBean.empty}">
...
</h:datatable>
```

Comment: A bit overwhelming if you can just do `#{bean.list.empty}` instead. Besides, this doesn't cover a list which is `null`. The EL `empty` keyword does.