# How to render a component if a parameter is presented in the URL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i have a div that contains some text
and i want to display it if a parameter is presented in the url

as in JSTL

```
<c:if ${param.loginError!=null}>

<div>

Wrong username/password

</div>

</c:if>
```

how to do that in JSF ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{param.loginError != null}">
    Wrong username/password.
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-html-elements)
- [How do I display a message if a jsf datatable is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985718/how-do-i-display-a-message-if-a-jsf-datatable-is-empty)

Comment: why using panelGroup not div ?

Comment: Because `<div>` doesn't have a `rendered` attribute :) It's a plain HTML element, not a JSF component. The JSF `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` generates a `<div>`, so it should be good enough.