# How to show JSF components if list is not null and has size() > 0

Tags: jsf, if-statement, el

How do I show JSF components if a list is not `null` and it has a `size() > 0`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985718/how-do-i-display-a-message-if-a-jsf-datatable-is-empty It has clear explanation for everything you need and more.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

EL offers the `empty` operator which checks both the nullness and emptiness of an object.

Thus, this should do:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" var="item" rendered="#{not empty bean.list}">
```

No need for a clumsy double check on both `null` and `size()` as suggested by other answers.

#### See also:

- [How do I display a message if a jsf datatable is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985718/how-do-i-display-a-message-if-a-jsf-datatable-is-empty/)
- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/)

Comment: hmm, interesting, never knew that there was an `Empty` operator in EL.  +! :)

Answer (score 2):

use **[rendered](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html)** attribute. most of the components have this attribute.This attribute;s main purpose is to render components conditionally.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.list}" rendered="{bean.list !=null &amp;&amp; bean.list.size()>0}" >
```

In the above piece of jsf code, datatable would only be rendered when list is not null and the size of list is greater than 0

Comment: The ugly `&amp;&amp;` can easily be replaced by the more readable `and`. Even more, the whole double check can easily be replaced by a single operator: `empty`.

Comment: @BalusC true, &amp; is ugly. as i commented under your question i din't know that empty operator existed. thanks for your feedback. i indeed find it rather ugly using &amp while applying conditional rendering to my components. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:outputText value="No Data to Display!" rendered="#{empty list1.List2}" />
<a href="#">
<h:outputText value="Data is present" rendered="#{not empty list1.List2}" /></a>
```

Or

```
<h:outputText value="#{not empty list1.List2 ? 'Data is Present' : 'No Data to Display'}" style="color:blue"/>
```

Comment: How is this better (in the context of the questionj) than the accepted answer?

Comment: @Kukeltje - It does add valid alternatives, which is helpful.